# Default Execute Anonymous in new developer edition fires all Heroku developers?

Tags: developer-console, developer-edition

I've just made a new Developer org. The default code in Execute Anonymous says this:

```
DELETE [Select ID from Developers__c where Product__c = 'Heroku'];
```

Is this an easter egg for everyone?